# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' -> not understanding what this error means in my project

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a website with Django. I want an index displaying rubriques, and when you click on a rubrique, the articles of this rubrique show.
Here is my models.py :

```
class Rubrique(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Here is my urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                       url(r'^(?i)(?P<rubrique_id>)[a-z]+/$',
                           views.rubriques, name='rubriques'),
                       url(r'^(?i)(?P<rubrique_id>)[a-z]+/(?P<article_id>)[a-z]+/$',
                           views.articles, name='articles'),
                       )
```

Here is my views.py :

```
def rubriques(request, rubrique_id):
    rubrique = get_object_or_404(Rubrique, pk=rubrique_id)  <-- The error points this line
    return render(request, 'rubriques/rubrique.html', {'rubrique': rubrique})
```

Aaand here is the error :

```
ValueError at /rubriques/sport/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The sport rubrique exists, and my template should be ok. What's wrong ? I have troubles with Django...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pk` field is a number by default, as in your model.

You have this in your url `(?P<rubrique_id>)[a-z]+` -> letters, not a number.

I don't know how are you calling your urls... but that's wrong for sure.

If you want to pass the signatures by its name, set the field as primary key:

```
class Rubrique(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

---

or, another option, change the lookup code:

```
rubrique = get_object_or_404(Rubrique, nom=rubrique_id)
```

You should set it as unique in this last case:

```
class Rubrique(models.Model):
     nom = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
     resume = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: An example url could be rubriques/sport/footbal

What should I put instead of pk ? I don't really understand this part

Comment: Ok, I did this change in my class. What should I change for 
rubrique = get_object_or_404(Rubrique, pk=rubrique_id) now ?

Comment: @ThomasPdobear if you've set `nom` as the primary key, you shouldn't need to change anything else.

Comment: Now I get a 404 page, I guess this is because Django doesn't find my rubrique. But it exists, I'm sure of that and can see it with the admin tool. I really don't see where the problem comes from !

Comment: @ThomasPdobear Have you done syncdb?, you've changed the model. You probably need to delete de database and generate it again.

Comment: Oh... Thanks ! I'm trying it.

Comment: I deleted it and generated a new one but I keep getting this 404 page.

Comment: I recreated my rubrique but keep getting that 404 page

Comment: @ThomasPdobear Your url might have another mistake. Try including the regex inside the parentheses: `(?P<rubrique_id>[a-z]+)`. And print the obtained value inside your view, to debug that it is receiving the correct string.

Comment: My regex was wrong. It print the correct thing ! But... I keep getting my 404 page. I'll dig a bit, should be a dumb mistake, I'm still a huge newbie with Django

Comment: All right, it works, but it's case sensitive. But this is not a problem ! Thank a lot !

Comment: @ThomasPdobear It is the primary key in your database, you shouldn't be having repeated values with different cases. You could call `lower()` in the parameter, to make your url ignore the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared any primary key field in the model, so Django automatically created an integer field to serve as primary key, so alias `pk` points to an autocreated field. It should be

```
class Rubrique(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Refer to Django [model field documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key) and [Automatic primary keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for details